# Sed replace multiple repetitions of a character with multiple repetitions of another character

Tags: regex, sed, substitution

If I have a piece of text like, but the number repetitions of the leading character can change.

> aaaabbbbaaaacccc

And I want to replace all the the `a` at the start of the text with `x` giving

> xxxxbbbbaaaacccc

I want to do this with a regular expression and `sed`, **not** with `tr` or `awk`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
echo aaaabbbbaaaacccc | sed ':l s/^\(x*\)a/\1x/;tl'
```

Comment: What if I wanted to replace each occurrence of 'a' with multiple characters, eg aaaabbbb becomes hellohellohellohellobbbb

Comment: `sed ':l s/^\(\(hello\)*\)a/\1hello/;tl'`

Answer (score 4):

One answer lies in using `sed`'s conditional branch mechanism, I think:

```
sed ':b; s/^\(x*\)a/\1x/; t b'
```

It replaces a sequence of zero of more `x`'s plus an `a` at the start of the line with the original set of `x`'s and another `x`.  The `:b` creates a label `b`; the `t b` jumps to label `b` if there's been a substitution performed since the last time `sed` checked.

The only time this runs into trouble is if you have a line like `aaaaxaab`; it skips past the first `x` and translates subsequent `a`'s when it shouldn't, by preference.

Testing on Mac OS X, I had to modify this to:

```
sed -e ':b' -e 's/^\(x*\)a/\1x/' -e 't b' <<< aaaaaxaaab
```

Using a single script argument, the line was not changed at all.  Mac OS X `sed` is funny on occasion about where newlines or new arguments must be used, in a way that GNU `sed` is not.  (It's the `:b` that has to be in its own argument or on its own line in the script; the substitution and the jump were OK in a single argument with a semi-colon in between.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that works on at least one line of input...

I had to do some weird thing to get the comments in...

```
echo '{
        h                 ;# copy the line
        s/^(a+)(.*)/\1/   ;# get just the leading aa  aaaa
        y/a/x/            ;# change aa to xx
        x                 ;# swap the xx and the line
        s/^(a+)(.*)/\2/   ;# remove the leading aa from the line  bbbbaaaacccc
        x                 ;# swap bbbbaaaacccc for xxxx
        G                 ;# append bbbbaaaacccc
        s/\n//            ;# get rid of the intervening new line
}' > s2.sed ; echo aaaabbbbaaaacccc | sed -rf s2.sed     

xxxxbbbbaaaacccc


echo '{
        h                 ;# copy the line
        s/^(a+)(.*)/\1/   ;# get just the leading aa  aaaa
        s/a/hello/g       ;# or change stuff to hello...
        x                 ;# swap the xx and the line
        s/^(a+)(.*)/\2/   ;# remove the leading aa from the line  bbbbaaaacccc
        x                 ;# swap bbbbaaaacccc for xxxx
        G                 ;# append bbbbaaaacccc
        s/\n//            ;# get rid of the intervening new line
}' > s3.sed ; echo aaaabbbb| sed -rf s3.sed     

hellohellohellohellobbbb
```

Comment: +1: Nice.  You could avoid the temporary file by using a multi-line quoted string as the argument to `sed`.  If you use a temporary file, you should remove the temporary file, too (preferably with a `trap` so if the user interrupts, the temporary is still removed).

Comment: I actually want the script saved. It's posted like this so you can c&p it to a shell.

Answer (score 2):

Perl too:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^a+/ "hello" x length($&) /e'  <<< aaaabbbbaaaacccc
hellohellohellohellobbbbaaaacccc
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed 's/a*/&\n/;h;y/a/x/;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Put a marker before the first non-a. Copy the line to the hold space. Change the line in the pattern space. Append the original line. Remove the unwanted section.

To change `a`'s to `hello`:

```
sed 's/a*/&\n/;h;s/a/hello/g;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You just do something like this:

```
echo 'aaaabbbbaaaacccc' | sed 's/^aaaa/xxxx/'
```

Comment: Should have said that I don't know in advance how many 'a' will be at start of line